# LDAP: Cannot authenticate users with period in username

Tags: php, ubuntu, ldap, openldap

Basically, this works:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://test.domain.pri -x -b dc=domain,dc=pri -D test1 -W
```

This does not:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://test.domain.pri -x -b dc=domain,dc=pri -D test.2 -W
```

The existence of a dot in the username seems to be the only determining factor here.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions! It turns out however that the client has something in place which replaces periods with spaces in the username. So the problem was not on my end!

Answer (score 0):

Try quoting the value for -D:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://test.domain.pri -x -b dc=domain,dc=pri -D "test.2" -W
```

My other thought: the -D param is supposed to provide the distinguished name (DN). Is "test.2" really a valid DN in your setup?

Answer (score 0):

For those who may still encounter this issue. Try using full UPN after -D. I found it to work with periods flawlessly:

```
    ldapsearch -H ldap://test.domain.pri -x -b dc=domain,dc=pri -D "test.2@domain.pri" -W
```

Comment: it may be you can extend you answer with some references or elaborate what does this key mean for future reference?